# ¿Son las formas potencial y condicional de un verbo en español los mismos tiempos verbales?

Tags: tiempos-verbales

Estaba tratando de aprender un poquito de japonés y me encuentro que entre los tantos tiempos verbales que tienen, uno es "condicional" y otro "potencial" con distintas conjugaciones.

Me fijo en nuestro idioma a ver a qué formas se refieren estos tiempos verbales para poder entender de qué se trata y me encuentro con [una página](https://proyectosantelmo.wordpress.com/2008/07/26/condicionalpotencial/) en donde habla del tiempo "condicional o potencial simple" y "condicional o potencial compuesto".

Mi pregunta es, en español, la forma condicional y potencial, ¿se refiere a los mismos tiempos verbales o son distintos tiempos verbales?

Comment: Creo que el potencial japonés y el español se refieren a cosas distintas. Si no recuerdo mal, el potencial japonés implica la capacidad de poder hacer algo, en el sentido de ser capaz de hacerlo (no de permiso). En español el potencial se refiere a que podrías hacer algo si antes pasara otra cosa.

Comment: @Pablo En español se habla indistintamente de "potencial" o "condicional" (en realidad, creo que el término "potencial" es más común).

Comment: Estuve investigando un poco y creo que los japoneses le llaman a nuestro condicional o potencial , presuntivo, o sea que su condicional y su potencial no se refiere ninguno a nuestro condicional o potencial, su potencial se traduce como "yo puedo" +  (verbo)  o "yo soy capaz de" + verbo y su condicional se traduce como "si (sujeto) + verbo <- (condicional) entonces (sujeto) + verbo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La palabra "potencial" tiene varios significados. Dejando de lado los significados relativos a la gramática, que directamente le dan a la palabra el sentido de "condicional", centrémonos en estos otros:

> [**potencial**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Trg1grH)
>
> 4. adj. Que puede suceder o existir, en contraposición de lo que existe.
>   7. m. Fuerza o poder disponibles de determinado orden. *Potencial militar, económico, industrial.*

La acepción 4 hace referencia al significado de "potencial" tal y como se entiende en español. Algo que tiene potencial es algo que podría llegar a ser. Fíjate que con "podría llegar a ser" ya estoy usando el condicional. Ejemplos:

- Yo me defendería en inglés si lo practicara un poco más (soy un hablante de inglés en potencia).
- Yo me lo comería, pero ya no tengo más hambre (soy un comilón en potencia).

Sin embargo, la acepción 7 hace referencia a una fuerza ya disponible en la actualidad. Esa acepción es la que se usa cuando se aprende japonés. Para ellos el potencial es la capacidad de poder hacer algo (en el presente). Así, tenemos:

- Hanasu (hablar) - Hanaseru (ser capaz de hablar)
- Iku (ir) - Ikeru (ser capaz de ir)

Ejemplo:

- Watashi wa nihongo wo hanaseru (yo puedo hablar japonés, tengo la capacidad (potencia) para ello).